# How to keep all CodeIt.Right custom rules in one project for sharing with other users?

Tags: c#, static-analysis

I am creating custom rules in CodeIt.Right. Is there a way to export all the rules in one project which can then be used on other computers? I want a solution such that the other users  may not need to copy the dll for each rule manually into the Rules folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is part of the Enterprise Edition of the product - you will find a walk-through here

```
[CodeIt.Right - Publishing Custom Configured Coding Standards to Your Team][1]
```

(remember, you need to use the Enterprise Edition of the product for this, Standard and Personal editions don't support automated rule library deployment)

BTW, please feel free to post your CodeIt.Right related questions in our community forum at http://submain.com/support/codeit.right - while we don't mind providing the product related help on StackOverflow, I'm not sure what this site's policy is about that.